# MySQL PDO - $sth->fetch() returns FALSE, but only the second time?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

The following is a code snippet of my application. Bear in mind that I am very, very new to PDO (as in, started figuring it out today) so I'm a bit confused.

Now, the `if` statement returns 1, as it should. This is expected. However, what's unexpected happens after I set `$node`: after setting it, it appears to be FALSE. What? Just a few lines before, my `fetch()` attempt returned the expected value, so I have no idea what's happening.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
    FROM flow
    INNER JOIN flow_strings
        USING(node_id)
    WHERE
        (
            parent = 0
            OR parent = :user_flow
        )
        AND source = 0
        AND string = :input
    ");
$sth->bindParam(':user_flow', $user->info->flow);
$sth->bindParam(':input', $input_sentence);
$sth->execute();

// If node exists.
if ($sth->fetch()->num_rows > 0)
{
    // Get the information for the node.
    $node = $sth->fetch();

[...] etc
```

I am guessing that the cursor is moved ahead, and then there's nothing left to read, so FALSE is returned. Surely there's a way to work around this, though! When I run `$sth->fetch()->num_rows`, I'm not trying to change anyything--I'm just trying to read a value. Is there a workaround? Am I doing something weird? I'm so lost, haha.

Thanks! :)

---

## EDIT:

`Notice: Undefined variable: node_count ... on line 56`

```
// Retrieve all child nodes under $parent.
$node_query = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
    FROM flow
    WHERE parent = :parent
    ");
$node_query->bindParam(':parent', $parent);
$node_query->execute();

// If child nodes exist.
if ($node_count = $node_query->fetch() && $node_count->num_rows > 0) // Line 56
{

[...] etc
```

Comment: have you tried reading documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the data array to some variable and use it without further fetches:

```
if (($row = $sth->fetch()) && $row->num_rows > 0) {
    // work with $row here
}
```

Comment: Though this example code does not actually work standalone (PHP complains that $row is not set due to the second part of the statement, despite the first) setting the array as a variable before doing anything else worked. I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathanael Shermett: "Though this example code does not actually work standalone" --- it's not right actually. This exact example does work standalone. "setting the array as a variable before doing anything else worked" --- it wouldn't change anything

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it, and I was getting an error until I made the modification I mentioned.

Comment: @Nathanael Shermett: yep, I'm 100% sure. If you give your **exact** code (without any modifications) and exact error (as you see it) - I could tell you what's happening

Comment: @Nathanael Shermett: oh right, it is my fault - you need to enclose `$node_count = $node_query->fetch()` in parenthesis. I update my answer